# How I should tune Sphinx?

Tags: sphinx

I make my first FullTextSearch app. Today I at last began test.

'test'

```
... the Whig national **ticket** victorious, he ... Democrats who **thought** he was ...
... also a self-**tought** architect. He ... and he always **thought** of how ...
... HTML (Hyper **Text** Mark-up ... Сервер HTML Hyper **Text** Markup Language. ...
... ,0 2. Aiced **test** ratio (Quick ratio ... 
... on the first **Tuesday**, after the first ...
```

'stop'

```
... ],Elm); OutText(Elm); **Stop**:=False; End; '2 ... 
.. a crucial **step** in the ... is an increasingly **steep** maturity-related... 
... CHIPSET FEATURES **SETUP** или INTEGRATED ... CHIPSET FEATURES **SETUP** или ... 
... Trisetum, Anisantna, **Stipa** и ... многие виды **Stipa**, Stipagrostis), что ...
```

My config:

```
source src1
{
type = csvpipe
csvpipe_command = /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/import.php 
csvpipe_field_string = title
csvpipe_field_string = content
csvpipe_attr_string  = path
}

 index test1
{   source          = src1
path            = /var/lib/sphinxsearch/data/test1
mlock           = 0
# morphology        = stem_en, stem_ru, soundex
min_word_len    = 2
html_strip      = 0
}
```

I commented the morphology string and reload Sphinx, but result the same. It looks like morphology still works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly the biggest thing to look at is

> morphology      = stem_en, stem_ru, soundex

Morphology is a very powerful function, in that it 'morphs' words going into the index (and in the query, so can match!), using various rules.

In your case you've enabled stemming, which 'normalizes' word endings, BUt auso have soundex, which is a 'sounds similar' algorithm. I believe designed for English, so dont know how well it does on Russian!

All of these means going to get 'similar' matches, not just exact word matches.

(*test* is just a word that happens to sound similar to other words, your *hyper* example, is a more unique sounding word)

---

Also realise its probably jsut a test script, but can pass multiple documents at once to buildExcerpts. So its should be MUCH more efficient, to compile the documents and call `buildExcepts` just once.

But even more interesting, is as you sourcing the the text from a sphinx attribute, can use the `SNIPPETS()` sphinx function (in `setSelect()`!) in the main query. SO you dont have to receive the full text, just to send back to sphinx. ie sphinx will fetch the text from attribute internally. even more efficient!

Comment: I commented  morphology string  and reload Sphinx, but situation the same. By the way on the other words like 'stop' too. So not only 'test', sorry.

Comment: Dear Barryhunter! What do You mean about 'compile documents and call buildExcerpts just once' and 'use snippets() in setSelect'. Please answer a little more detailed!!!

Comment: At the monent, you call 'buildExcerpts' many times. Once per document. Each call is a network round trip to sphinx. Instead build an array of documents first, pass that to buildExcerpts, then process the results. Or use the SNIPPET() function instead of buildExcepts (dcoumented in SphinxQL section, but should work in SphinxAPI)